# Pyinstaller PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: run.exe

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller

I have a flask app that I made into a gui desktop app with flaskwebgui. I am trying to use pyinstaller to make it an executable for distribution to co-workers. I keep getting this error when I am running pyinstaller:

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\users\myname\pycharmprojects\myprojectname\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe'

WHAT I'M RUNNING: pyinstaller app.py -F --add-data "templates;templates" --add-data "static;static"

The app works great on my computer. I was able to get pyinstaller to work when i used -w but I don't think I want to use that.

When using -w I was able to run it just fine on my computer, but when I gave it to a co-worker it gave a 500 error when the app made an api request.

Comment: It might be the antivirus blocking this, try temporarily disabling it. You could also try running the cmd as admin and/or running the spec file that was generated `pyinstaller app.spec`. Internal server error can be caused by a variety of reasons, maybe start by checking if all the paths specified in your app are relative and not absolute.